# Can I charge my iPhone using the USB-A port of my "AV Multiport adapter"?

Tags: iphone, usb, charging, lightning, video-adapter

I have a macbook 12', with "AV Multiport adapter":

- the USB-C port is used for charging
- the HDVI port for the monitor
- and the USB-A is used to charge my iPhone (and to work with xCode).

I'm using the iPhone cable (USB-A to lightning plug), that is provided with the iPhone charger.

Is this configuration fine? Or am I going to damage the iPhone battery?
I guess I have lower performance, but that's not an issue for me, as long as it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, this is totally fine.**

Of course, your MacBook will need to be on for it to deliver power, and how fast your iPhone charges may depend on what else your MacBook is doing at the time, but this is totally safe and will not damage your devices or batteries.